# Do a certain backend operation on clicking Django Admin save button

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In a library system, I have the Userbooks (refers to books issued by a user) object registered with Django Admin. And when Django Admin creates a Userbooks object and saves it, the Book object (refers to books in library, also registered with Django Admin) associated with that UserBook with a one_to_one relationship, needs to have its boolean field 'is_issued' to be set to true. How can I do this backend action when Admin clicks the 'save' button?

Comment: Try using `default=True` on `is_issued` field

Comment: But I need to set is_issued=True only after the book is issued by an user..

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to either you use [pre save signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/) or just override the save method to do whatever operation use want

```
class ModelB(models.Model):
    def save(self):
        # add logic to change is_issue value to True
        super(ModelB, self).save()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the logic to set is_issued = True inside save method, I need to access one field of ModelB's current instance. How can I do that?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did the job.. The upvote was not counted due to low rep though:(

Comment: This logic runs on Admin save only or runs in any save on the model?

Comment: This save would run on model save. This won't distinguish between admin save or any other save.

There are ways to just limit this option just on admin save too.

Answer (score 1):

In the question you specifically asked that this action should happen when the admin tries to save it from admin. The solution suggested by @pansul-bhatt does the same thing on Model save. Even the alternative(Handling pre-save signal) would do the same thing. So even if you save the model from anywhere else in the code you will set `is_issued` as `True`.

The better way to do it is to override the save_model on the UserbooksAdmin.

```
class UserBookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
           obj.is_issued = True
           obj.save()
```

This should be enough to solve your problem. But there are other hooks available with Django Admin.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!